# Removing potassium chloride crystals from a mineral composed of manganese dioxides

Tags: solutions, solubility

How can I remove crystals of potassium chloride from a mineral composed of manganese dioxides?
Hey, i'm a high school student trying to do a good cryptomelane sample to use in my scientific project. 
I was able to develop the cryptomelane, but after some necessary processes, the mineral was crusted with crystals of potassium chloride, what would be the best process to remove this salt?

Answer (score 2):

$\ce{MnO2}$ is insoluble in water -- I would expect with a good deal of confidence that the mineral cryptomelane is also insoluble. $\ce{KCl}$ by contrast is highly soluble.

I would just treat the sample with cold water and filter out the dissolved $\ce{KCl}$ (e.g. with a Buchner funnel and filter paper). Then dry with heat.

I would choose a fine-grain filter paper though because, though insoluble, $\ce{MnO2}$ particles could still be small enough to filter through course paper, like coffee filters (from experience).